# separating keys and objects from NSMutable dictionary and use the values in insert command of sqlite

Tags: iphone, insert, sqlite, nsmutabledictionary

hi folks i am developing an sqlite application in iphone.
since i am new to this application, i dont how to use the key and objects from NSMutableDictionary in the command of insert statement of sqlite.
for example , i want the insert statement in the following format.

INSERT INTO TABLENAME (COLUMN NAMES AS KEYS FROM NSMUTABLEDICTIONRY) VALUES (VALUES AS OBJECTS FROM NSMUTABLEDICTIONARY)
please help me out.
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have actually very little knowledge about SQL, but maybe something like this will help you:

```
NSDictionary *myDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              @"Foo", @"Bar",
                              @"Foz", @"Baz",
                              nil];

NSMutableString *keys = [NSMutableString string];
NSMutableString *values = [NSMutableString string];
for (NSString *key in myDictionary) {
    [keys appendFormat:@"%@,", key];
    [values appendFormat:@"%@,", [myDictionary objectForKey:key]];
}
// remove last ,
[keys deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange([keys length]-1, 1)];
[values deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange([values length]-1, 1)]; 
NSString *sqlQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO TABLENAME %@ VALUES %@", keys, values];

// sqlQuery = INSERT INTO TABLENAME Bar,Baz VALUES Foo,Foz
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *keys = [dictionary allKeys];
NSMutableArray *values = [NSMutableArray array];
for (id k in keys)
    [values addObject:[dictionary objectForKey:k]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use fast enumeration to loop through the dictionary:

```
NSDictionary *abc;
for (NSString *key in abc) {
     NSObject *foo = [abc objectForKey:key];
}
```

With that it should be easy to construct your statement.